# grep for matching 1 to 2 digits in a sequence of numbers

Tags: grep

I have below numbers in a file

```
44700101
44700201
44700301
44700401
44700501
44700601
44700701
44700801
44700901
44701001
```

want to fetch the above numbers whose 5th and 6th digits are greater than 5 USING GREP WILDCARDS.

something like "grep ....[6-10].. file" should yield below

```
44700601
44700701
44700801
44700901
44701001
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***gawk*** (GNU awk) approach:

```
awk '{split($0,a,"")}int(a[5]a[6])>5' file
```

---

*gawk* has the ability for *FS* and for the *third* argument to `split()` to be null strings

- `split($0,a,"")` - splits the numeric string into separate numbers (filling array `a`)
- `int(a[5]a[6])>5` - print the line if *integer* representation of the 5th and 6th numbers is greater than 5

---

***grep*** approach:

```
grep '^[0-9]\{4\}\([1-9]\|0[6-9]\).*' file
```

The output (for both approaches):

```
44700601
44700701
44700801
44700901
44701001
```

Comment: @EdMorton, I've added a note (*gawk has the ability ...*)

Answer (score 0):

Just use awk:

```
$ awk 'substr($0,5,2)+0 > 5' file
44700601
44700701
44700801
44700901
44701001
```